# Find whether a particular cell of a table has an img tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am generating a table dynamically using Django.
The same table template is used to generate a variety of tables depending on the data supplied. In one scenario a particular column contains image tags.
Since my table is editable (using jquery) the image cell also becomes editable and removes my content.
I want some special behavior on double click of such cells like say upload an image. How do I accomplish this with a jquery?
My script for making the table editable is given below.

```
       $(function() {
            $("td").dblclick(function() {
                var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

                $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
                $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
                $(this).children().first().focus();

                $(this).children().first().keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        var newContent = $(this).val();
                        $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                    }
                });
                $(this).children().first().blur(function() {
                    $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
                    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if that cell have an image or not -

```
 $("td").dblclick(function() {
       var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
       var hasImage = $('img',this).length > 0;
       if(hasImage){
          // image exist
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the table cells with images, add a class when you're adding it.  Then you can do something like this:

```
   $(function() {
        $("td").dblclick(function() {
            if (this.classList.contains('img')) return;
            // Will not continue if this is an image class.

            var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
            [...]
        });
    });
```

Comment: I do not know the content of the table class. In case of an image it is being rendered by the server side. So I cant add a class to it
I could add a class tag to my img tags though. If it helps you to solve the problem that is :)

Comment: Take it like this
<td> XYZ </td>
I dont know what XYZ is could be text numbers or an image or a list.